# Mint 18.1 Wired network not working

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet

I'm struggling to get my wired network to work.  I've tried re-installing the network drivers, etc.  My wireless connection is working fine.

System:

```
Kernel: 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64 (64 bit) 
Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7
Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 15
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:e2104000-e2104fff memory:e2100000-e2103fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3165
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 81
   serial: 70:1c:e7:8b:27:f7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-78-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:130 memory:e2200000-e2201fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: veth9c0371b
   serial: c2:3a:8c:86:56:de
   size: 10Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

lspci

```
...
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
...
```

**Update: 1**

ifconfig:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:31:e4:fe:0d  
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:31ff:fee4:fe0d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:8794028 (8.7 MB)  TX bytes:5544088 (5.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:89830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:89830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:118414988 (118.4 MB)  TX bytes:118414988 (118.4 MB)

veth9c0371b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c2:3a:8c:86:56:de  
      inet6 addr: fe80::c03a:8cff:fe86:56de/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2046219 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:2253074 (2.2 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:1c:e7:8b:27:f7  
      inet addr:192.168.0.22  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::bac:ff84:3adc:7155/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1120854 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:944085 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:869874166 (869.8 MB)  TX bytes:689796504 (689.7 MB)
```

**Update: 2**

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
```

sudo service networking restart

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

sudo systemctl status networking.service

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
       └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-31 14:41:55 SAST; 1min 52s ago
 Docs: man:interfaces(5)
Process: 21730 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 21759 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 21751 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 21759 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: 
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: exiting.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Failed to bring up enp7s0.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

sudo journalctl -xe

```
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: All rights reserved.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: All rights reserved.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: 
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr root[21782]: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Cannot find device "enp7s0"
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: Error getting hardware address for "enp7s0": No such device
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Error getting hardware address for "enp7s0": No such device
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: exiting.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: 
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: 
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr dhclient[21778]: exiting.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Failed to bring up enp7s0.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr sudo[21721]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 31 14:42:13 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
May 31 14:42:13 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
May 31 14:42:13 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 31 14:42:13 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
May 31 14:42:47 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
May 31 14:42:47 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
May 31 14:42:47 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 31 14:42:47 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
May 31 14:42:50 Jarngreipr ntpd[20438]: 45.222.43.250 local addr 192.168.0.203 -> <null>
May 31 14:42:55 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
May 31 14:42:55 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
May 31 14:42:55 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 31 14:42:55 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
May 31 14:43:07 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
May 31 14:43:07 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
May 31 14:43:07 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 31 14:43:07 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
May 31 14:43:12 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
May 31 14:43:12 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
May 31 14:43:12 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 31 14:43:12 Jarngreipr kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
May 31 14:43:21 Jarngreipr sudo[21864]:    andre : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/andre ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
May 31 14:43:21 Jarngreipr sudo[21864]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I've noticed `May 31 14:41:55 Jarngreipr ifup[21759]: Cannot find device "enp7s0"`

**Update: 3**

ip link show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 70:1c:e7:8b:27:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 02:42:02:d7:a4:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(Looks like docker took it over?)
Where can I look next?

Comment: what is the output of `/etc/network/interfaces`  and `ifconfig`?

Comment: @GAD3R Updated the question

Comment: Please add the `ip link show` output , it will show you the exact eth interface name

Comment: @GAD3R Update 3

Comment: `PCIe Bus Error` sounds like some card is not correctly seated. `8086:9d15` is probably the PCI root hub (but you didn't give enough information to identify it). Try reseating all cards, see if the error persists. If it still doesn't work, it's probably a driver problem: Look in `demsg` or `journalctl` for messages related to the network card, right after boot. With all those incomplete snippets, it's difficult to see what's really going in, so if it still fails, put complete output if `dmesg` after boot into a pastebin, and edit question with link.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
```

Restart the network .

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: I've updated the question (Update 2)

Comment: @TungstenX comment the 2 added line to your `interfaces` conf file then run `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` and reboot

Comment: I've done this already: `r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.041.00-1)`

Comment: Why is this only requiredafter an upgrade?